# ¿problema pasando datos mediante AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsonp

## Pregunta

Cree hace unos días un `select` el cual se completa de manera automática mediante una `DB`, pedí ayuda para poder crear un `container` que tuviera los campos necesarios traídos de la `db`, el problema es que cuando intento hacerlo por método AJAX para traer los datos y completar la tabla este me da un error y no logro encontrar donde este se ubica o cual es el problema del traspaso de datos.

Seria de gran ayuda si alguien me indica donde esta mi error.

**Codigo JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#boton_asignar',function traer_usuarios(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'api/traer_usuarios',
    data: $('#form_usuario').serialize(),
    success: function(json) {
      if (json.success == 1) {
        var usuariosNoAsignados = json.usuariosNoAsignados;
        var usuariosAsignados = json.usuariosAsignados;
        var mostrarTodo = $('<!-- Default box --><div class="box" id="caja_secundaria"><!-- Custom Tabs (Pulled to the right) --><div class="nav-tabs-custom"><ul class="nav nav-tabs pull-rigth"><li class="active"><a href="#tab_2-2" data-toggle="tab"><label for="">Usuario</label></a></li><li class="pull-left header"></li></ul><div class="tab-content"><div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1-1"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-6"><label for="">Usuarios no asignados</label></div><div class="col-md-6"><label for="">Usuarios asignados</label></div></div></div><!-- /.tab-pane --></div></div></div>');
        $('#mostrarDatos').prepend(mostrarTodo);
        for (var i = 0; i < usuariosNoAsignados.length; i++) {
          $('#ejecutivos').append('<option class="opcion" value="' + usuariosNoAsignados[i][0] + '">' + usuariosNoAsignados[i][0] + '</option>');
        }
        // AQUI PONER EL ELSE DE LA WEA
      }
    },
    error: function( /*xhr, status*/ ) {
      msg_box_alert(/*xhr.responsetext*/);
    }
    });
  });
```

**PD: Trabajo en un framework llamado Ocrend, por ende la URL es un API REST que me envía desde el POST al modelo y ahí se busca la función que corresponde, luego del modelo envió los datos de vuelta como variables por mensaje.**

**Mensaje de error:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aquí esta la carpeta donde llega desde JS**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Error al escribir la URL en la pagina :**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aquí dejo un API que funciona de la misma forma, este esta funcional y no me da problemas:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y cual es el mensaje de error que te sale ?

Comment: @CamiloVasquez ahi puse la imagen del error camilo, espero lograr encontrar una solución.

Comment: El error 500 e sun error de servidor por lo cual debe haber algún problema en traer_usuarios, revisa en el network que mensaje te arroja esa petición

Comment: @CamiloVasquez no manda errores en el network camilo

Comment: La primera prueba que deberías hacer es colocar la URL que te da error en el navegador y probar si devuelve algo. Todo parece indicar, como ha dicho @CamiloVasquez, que hay un error del lado del servidor. O bien que la URL esté mal escrita: `api/traer_usuarios`. ¿El script que llama a Ajax se encuentra en la carpeta `intranietsen`?

Comment: @A.Cedano Hola!, el problema es que esa URL no me envia a ningun lado ya que el Framework la envia a la carpeta correspondiente a Api/POST/traer_usuario y desde ahi se envia al modelo, pondre una imagen de como son las carpetas a las cuales llega y de que manera lo envio al modelo al final de la pregunta.

Comment: Debe enviarte a algún lado, fíjate en la imagen, que se construye una URL (donde empieza por `http://`) esa es la URL a la que se envía la petición POST. Si tú escribes esa URL en el navegador generalmente debería responder. Es como si tú ahora mismo consultas cualquier API de cualquier servicio REST que no necesite credenciales. la API te respondería adecuadamente. El error 500 significa que la URL está mal, o que el servicio REST funciona mal en el servidor. [Esta es una prueba](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=LosAngeles,usa) de consulta de una API de Google.

Comment: Es muy probable que la url de tu petición Ajax debería estar escrita así más o menos: `url: 'api/traer_usuarios/post.php/',` o de otra forma parecida. Eso debe decírtelo la API que estás usando en su documentación. Si no pones la URL como debe ir, nunca te va a funcionar.

Comment: @A.Cedano Actualice la pregunta con mas información ya que existe otra función en JS que esta declarada de la misma manera y esta funciona sin problemas.

Comment: Revisa la documentación de la API, allí debe estar indicado cómo debes construir la URL para traer usuarios.

Comment: Les comento que logre fixear el problema, y este venia desde el modelo que estaba haciendo mal una consulta, lo arregle y todo funciona de manera normal! Gracias de todas maneras

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Los problemas de este tipo suelen suceder cuando no hay control total del `framework`, después de buscar en el archivo `js` asociado a esa vista, al `API REST` asociado que era por método `POST` y luego finalizar llegando al `modelo` logre darme cuenta que el problema provenía de este lugar, al arreglarlo todo funciono de buena manera, solo habia un problema de sintaxis en la consulta que hacia desde la base de datos y esto no lograba encontrar los datos que enviaba de vuelta mediante Ajax.